# Is there any function that can pipe all output into text file in rust

Tags: rust

I have this code that extract wifi saved password in our system. I just want it to save all it's output in a text file, I have tried few options but was not able to figure out how to do it.

`Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "Passdump"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.52"

features = [
    "Data_Xml_Dom",
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Foundation_Collections",
    "Win32_NetworkManagement_WiFi",
    "Win32_Security",
    "Win32_System_Com",
    "Win32_System_Threading",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
]
```

#That is cargo.toml and given below is main.rs
I have tried writeln fn but that will not allow me to write error into the file
So i m confused right now what to use with this mentioned code

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use std::{ffi::OsString, os::windows::ffi::OsStringExt};

use windows::{
    core::{GUID, HSTRING, PCWSTR, PWSTR},
    Data::Xml::Dom::{XmlDocument, XmlElement},
    Win32::{
        Foundation::{ERROR_SUCCESS, HANDLE, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, WIN32_ERROR},
        NetworkManagement::WiFi::{
            WlanCloseHandle, WlanEnumInterfaces, WlanFreeMemory, WlanGetProfile,
            WlanGetProfileList, WlanOpenHandle, WLAN_API_VERSION_2_0, WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO,
            WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST, WLAN_PROFILE_GET_PLAINTEXT_KEY, WLAN_PROFILE_INFO_LIST,
        },
    },
};

fn open_wlan_handle(api_version: u32) -> Result<HANDLE, windows::core::Error> {
    let mut negotiatied_version = 0;
    let mut wlan_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    let result = unsafe {
        WlanOpenHandle(
            api_version,
            None,
            &mut negotiatied_version,
            &mut wlan_handle,
        )
    };

    WIN32_ERROR(result).ok()?;

    Ok(wlan_handle)
}

fn enum_wlan_interfaces(
    handle: HANDLE,
) -> Result<*mut WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST, windows::core::Error> {
    let mut interface_ptr = std::ptr::null_mut();

    let result = unsafe { WlanEnumInterfaces(handle, None, &mut interface_ptr) };

    WIN32_ERROR(result).ok()?;

    Ok(interface_ptr)
}

fn grab_interface_profiles(
    handle: HANDLE,
    interface_guid: &GUID,
) -> Result<*const WLAN_PROFILE_INFO_LIST, windows::core::Error> {
    let mut wlan_profiles_ptr = std::ptr::null_mut();

    let result =
        unsafe { WlanGetProfileList(handle, interface_guid, None, &mut wlan_profiles_ptr) };

    WIN32_ERROR(result).ok()?;

    Ok(wlan_profiles_ptr)
}
fn parse_utf16_slice(string_slice: &[u16]) -> Option<OsString> {
    let null_index = string_slice.iter().position(|c| c == &0)?;
    Some(OsString::from_wide(&string_slice[..null_index]))
}

fn load_xml_data(xml: &OsString) -> Result<XmlDocument, windows::core::Error> {
    let xml_document = XmlDocument::new()?;
    xml_document.LoadXml(&HSTRING::from(xml))?;
    Ok(xml_document)
}

fn traverse_xml_tree(xml: &XmlElement, node_path: &[&str]) -> Option<String> {
    let mut subtree_list = xml.ChildNodes().ok()?;
    let last_node_name: &&str = node_path.last()?;

    'node_traverse: for node in node_path {
        let node_name: OsString = OsString::from_wide(&node.encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>());

        for subtree_value in &subtree_list {
            let element_name = match subtree_value.NodeName() {
                Ok(name) => name,
                Err(_) => continue,
            };

            if element_name.to_os_string() == node_name {
                if element_name.to_os_string().to_string_lossy().to_string()
                    == last_node_name.to_string()
                {
                    return Some(subtree_value.InnerText().ok()?.to_string());
                }

                subtree_list = subtree_value.ChildNodes().ok()?;
                continue 'node_traverse;
            }
        }
    }

    None
}

fn get_profile_xml(
    handle: HANDLE,
    interface_guid: &GUID,
    profile_name: &OsString,
) -> Result<OsString, windows::core::Error> {
    let mut profile_xml_data = PWSTR::null();
    let mut profile_get_flags = WLAN_PROFILE_GET_PLAINTEXT_KEY;

    let result = unsafe {
        WlanGetProfile(
            handle,
            interface_guid,
            PCWSTR(HSTRING::from(profile_name).as_ptr()),
            None,
            &mut profile_xml_data,
            Some(&mut profile_get_flags),
            None,
        )
    };

    WIN32_ERROR(result).ok()?;

    let xml_string = match unsafe { profile_xml_data.to_hstring() } {
        Ok(data) => data,
        Err(e) => {
            unsafe { WlanFreeMemory(profile_xml_data.as_ptr().cast()) };
            return Err(e);
        }
    };

    Ok(xml_string.to_os_string())
}

fn main() {
    let wlan_handle = open_wlan_handle(WLAN_API_VERSION_2_0).expect("Failed to open WLAN handle!");

    let interface_ptr = match enum_wlan_interfaces(wlan_handle) {
        Ok(interfaces) => interfaces,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to get the wireless interfaces: {:?}", e);
            unsafe { WlanCloseHandle(wlan_handle, None) };
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
    };

    let interfaces_list = unsafe {
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(
            (*interface_ptr).InterfaceInfo.as_ptr(),
            (*interface_ptr).dwNumberOfItems as usize,
        )
    };

    for interface_info in interfaces_list {
        let interface_description =
            match parse_utf16_slice(interface_info.strInterfaceDescription.as_slice()) {
                Some(name) => name,
                None => {
                    eprintln!("could not parse our interface description");
                    continue;
                }
            };

        let wlan_profile_ptr =
            match grab_interface_profiles(wlan_handle, &interface_info.InterfaceGuid) {
                Ok(profiles) => profiles,
                Err(_e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to retrive profiles");
                    continue;
                }
            };

        let wlan_profile_list = unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(
                (*wlan_profile_ptr).ProfileInfo.as_ptr(),
                (*wlan_profile_ptr).dwNumberOfItems as usize,
            )
        };

        for profile in wlan_profile_list {
            let profile_name: OsString = match parse_utf16_slice(&profile.strProfileName) {
                Some(name) => name,
                None => {
                    eprintln!("could not parse profile name");
                    continue;
                }
            };

            let profile_xml_data =
                match get_profile_xml(wlan_handle, &interface_info.InterfaceGuid, &profile_name) {
                    Ok(data) => data,
                    Err(_e) => {
                        eprintln!("Failed to extract XML data");
                        continue;
                    }
                };

            let xml_document = match load_xml_data(&profile_xml_data) {
                Ok(xml) => xml,
                Err(_e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to extract XML document");
                    continue;
                }
            };

            let root = match xml_document.DocumentElement() {
                Ok(root) => root,
                Err(_e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to get document root for profile XML");
                    continue;
                }
            };

            let auth_type = match traverse_xml_tree(
                &root,
                &["MSM", "security", "authEncryption", "authentication"],
            ) {
                Some(t) => t,
                None => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to get the auth type for this profile");
                    continue;
                }
            };

            match auth_type.as_str() {
                "open" => {
                    println!(
                        "Wi-Fi Name: {}, No password",
                        profile_name.to_string_lossy().to_string()
                    );
                }
                "WPA2" | "WPA2PSK" => {
                    if let Some(password) =
                        traverse_xml_tree(&root, &["MSM", "security", "sharedKey", "keyMaterial"])
                    {
                        println!(
                            "Wi-Fi Name: {}, Authentication: {}, Password: {}",
                            profile_name.to_string_lossy().to_string(),
                            auth_type,
                            password
                        )
                    }
                }
                _ => {
                    println!(
                        "Wi-Fi Name: {}, Authentication: {}",
                        profile_name.to_string_lossy().to_string(),
                        auth_type
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    unsafe { WlanFreeMemory(interface_ptr.cast()) };
    unsafe { WlanCloseHandle(wlan_handle, None) };
}
```

I have read other related queries but couldnot able to find that work with given code

Comment: don't spam unrelated tags please